# Why do indicators sometimes work well and sometimes not? writing down huffman codes

Tags: c++

I have a problem because I'm programming a simplified version of huffman coding and I have a problem while creating the code, namely the program every second time it doesn't work and I don't know what's the reason, I gets this message "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)" I don't include the whole code, because I guess it's unnecessary.

> [when it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9aiT.png)
>
> [when it doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlLCn.png)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<vector>
#include<string.h>
#include<queue>
#include<cstddef>
using namespace std;
 
int counter = 0;
struct characters
{
    char a;
    string code;
    unsigned long likehood;
    characters *left, *right;
};

struct huffman_code
{
    char a;
    string code;
};
```

the function that creates the code, Here's the problem attached to the pictures.

```
void encode(characters* root, string str, vector<huffman_code> &huffmanCode)
{
    if (root == nullptr)
        return;

    // found a leaf node
    if (!root->left && !root->right) {
        huffmanCode[counter].code = str; **PROBLEM IS HEAR**
        huffmanCode[counter].a = root->a;
        counter++;
    }

    encode(root->left, str + "0", huffmanCode);
    encode(root->right, str + "1", huffmanCode);
}


}
```

```
int main()
{
    
    vector<characters> how_many_times;
    how_many_times.reserve(26);
    string C="abcdefghijklmnoprqestuvwxyz", rows="abbceeeddfff";
    priority_queue<characters*, vector<characters*>, characters_comparsion> Q;
    characters *w;
    unsigned long how_many;
    for(int i=0; i<26; i++)
    {
        how_many_times[i].a = C[i];
        how_many_times[i].likehood=0;
        how_many_times[i].left = NULL;
        how_many_times[i].right = NULL;
    }
    
    
    unsigned long length = rows.length();
    
    for(unsigned long i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<26; j++)
        {
            if(how_many_times[j].a==rows[i])
            {
                how_many_times[j].likehood++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    for(unsigned long i=0; i<26; i++)
    {
        if(how_many_times[i].likehood!=0)
        {
            Q.push(&how_many_times[i]);
        }
    }
     
    how_many = Q.size();
     
  vector<huffman_code> huffmanCode;
  huffmanCode.reserve(how_many);
 
    w = Huffman(Q);
   
    encode(w, "", huffmanCode);
  
    cout<<"Cody Huffmana: "<<endl;
    for(int i=0; i<how_many; i++)
    {
        cout<<huffmanCode[i].a<<" "<<huffmanCode[i].code<<endl;
    }
      
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You never added elements to `how_many_times` or `huffmanCode`; you only reserved space for them.

Every access to those non-existent elements (particularly the assignments) has undefined behaviour.

You'll need to re-read the chapter in your book about using vectors.